# ecc-algorithm in contiki cooja simulator compilation error `cpsid i'

Tags: contiki

when i compile ecc-algorithm in contiki cooja simulator an error message shows like this ./cmsis_gcc.h: Assembler messages: ./cmsis_gcc.h:27: Error: no such instruction: `cpsid i'

Answer (score 0):

`cpsid i` is an ARM instruction for disabling IRQ interrupts -- are you sure you are compiling correctly? Such an instruction makes no sense if making a build for a PC-simulator

Comment: Thanks for your reply ...I need to generate simulation of ecc-algorithm in cooja simulator can please help me